# Fabric.js - Set cursor to free drawing brush size and colour

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Say I have a round solid brush with a size of 10, how can I change the cursor to indicate to the user that's what will be drawn on the canvas?

I see these is an option for a `freeDrawingCursor`, but that's for regular cursors, e.g. Crosshair or pointer.

Any ideas?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39263975/2577116

Answer (score 1):

checking this:

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor
```

It looks like you can define a cursor with a png file.

You could create a small temporary canvas of the size of cursor, paint over it with the brush, export as a png dataurl and use as a cursor.

When the user on your web app select a cursor width:
- create an offscreen canvas of width and height of brush size
- draw a circle of selected width and color
- export canvas to dataurl
- create an image of width and height of brush size, use dataurl as image source
- on image loaded set that as your mouse cursor.

Comment: you misunderstood my answer.Or i poorly wrote it.