# JavaScript - Dynamically create SVG and modify for cursor

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Say I have a HTML5 canvas (In this case using fabric.js), and I want to change the cursor over the canvas to represent whatever brush size and colour has been selected. I'm thinking there should be a way to do this by changing an SVG's properties (size & colour) dynamically with JS so we don't have to use multiple images. Any ideas on if this is possible?

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(c, {
            isDrawingMode: true,
            freeDrawingCursor: 'url("img/cursor.svg"), auto'
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think freeDrawingCursor is just looking for normal css property names. Here is an example of how to have a fabric object represent the cursor size and color:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  isDrawingMode: true,
  freeDrawingCursor: 'none'
});

canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 10;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = '#9f9';

var mousecursor = new fabric.Circle({ 
  left: 0, 
  top: 0, 
  radius: canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width / 2, 
  fill: canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color, 
  originX: 'right', 
  originY: 'bottom',
})

canvas.add(mousecursor);

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(obj) {
  mousecursor.top = obj.e.y - mousecursor.radius;
  mousecursor.left = obj.e.x - mousecursor.radius;
  canvas.renderAll()
})

canvas.on('mouse:out', function(obj) {
  // put circle off screen
  mousecursor.top = -100;
  mousecursor.left = -100;
  canvas.renderAll()
})
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is a really great idea! I'm finding in my own app the circle cursor is not aligned with the actual position of where the line is being drawn, but also when you exit drawing mode the cursor remains. Would you just set the opacity to 0 or something? http://codepen.io/paulcredmond/pen/GqLmgb

Comment: note the code where the originX and originY are set. I noticed those settings are needed to get the circle to be in the same place as where the drawing output was happening. Setting opacity to 0 on mouse:out might work. A more ideal solution would probably be to remove the object from the canvas on mouse:exit but just keep a reference to it so when you go back over the canvas you ca add it back.

Comment: It doesn't seem there is a `mouse:exit` function. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: brilliant! Thank you so much.

Comment: @STHayden: Maybe I'm the only one but when running your snippet the circle keeps stuck in the top left corner. Anyway thanks for the inspiration; I already solved it for me (see my answer below).

Answer (score 3):

Existing answers didn't work for me in 2020. Try the following:

```
    this.canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
    this.canvas.freeDrawingCursor = 'none';

    const mousecursor = new fabric.Circle({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        radius: this.canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width / 2,
        fill: this.canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color,
        originX: 'right',
        originY: 'bottom',
    });

    this.canvas.add(mousecursor);

    // Cursor in canvas
    this.canvas.on('mouse:move', event => {
        mousecursor.top = event.e.layerY + mousecursor.radius;
        mousecursor.left = event.e.layerX + mousecursor.radius;
        this.canvas.renderAll();
    });

    // Cursor out of canvas
    this.canvas.on('mouse:out', event => {
        mousecursor.top = -100;
        mousecursor.left = -100;
        this.canvas.renderAll();
    });
```

Worked fine with Angular 7.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same and found my way to this question. Unfortunately the solution by STHayden is not working for me. So I've modified it a bit and came up with the code below. It uses two canvas layers, the bottom for drawing, the top for the "cursor". Works pretty well for me now, maybe someone will find it helpful :)

```js
//drawing layer
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("draw", {
  isDrawingMode: true,
  freeDrawingCursor: 'none'
});
//mouse cursor layer
var cursor = new fabric.StaticCanvas("cursor");

canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 20;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = '#ff0000';

var cursorOpacity = .5;
//create cursor and place it off screen
var mousecursor = new fabric.Circle({ 
  left: -100, 
  top: -100, 
  radius: canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width / 2, 
  fill: "rgba(255,0,0," + cursorOpacity + ")",
  stroke: "black",
  originX: 'center', 
  originY: 'center'
});

cursor.add(mousecursor);

//redraw cursor on new mouse position when moved
canvas.on('mouse:move', function (evt) {
  var mouse = this.getPointer(evt.e);  
  mousecursor
    .set({
      top: mouse.y,
      left: mouse.x
    })
    .setCoords()
    .canvas.renderAll();
});

//put cursor off screen again when mouse is leaving
canvas.on('mouse:out', function () {
  mousecursor
    .set({
      top: mousecursor.originalState.top,
      left: mousecursor.originalState.left
    })
    .setCoords()
    .canvas.renderAll();
});

//while brush size is changed show cursor in center of canvas
document.getElementById("size").oninput = function () {
  var size = parseInt(this.value, 10);
  mousecursor
    .center()
    .set({
      radius: size/2
    })
    .setCoords()
    .canvas.renderAll();
};

//after brush size has been changed move offscreen, update brush size
document.getElementById("size").onchange = function () {
  var size = parseInt(this.value, 10);
  canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = size;
  mousecursor
    .set({
      left: mousecursor.originalState.left,
      top: mousecursor.originalState.top,
      radius: size/2
    })
    .setCoords()
    .canvas.renderAll();
};

//change mousecursor opacity
document.getElementById("opacity").onchange = function () {
  cursorOpacity = this.value;
  var fill = mousecursor.fill.split(",");
  fill[fill.length-1] = cursorOpacity + ")";
  mousecursor.fill = fill.join(",");
};

//change drawing color
document.getElementById("color").onchange = function () {
  canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = this.value;  
  var bigint = parseInt(this.value.replace("#", ""), 16);
  var r = (bigint >> 16) & 255;
  var g = (bigint >> 8) & 255;
  var b = bigint & 255;  
  mousecursor.fill = "rgba(" + [r,g,b,cursorOpacity].join(",") + ")";
};
```

```css
#cont {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}

#cont canvas, .canvas-container {
  position: absolute!important;
  left: 0!important;
  top: 0!important;
  width: 100%!important;
  height: 100%!important;
}

#cursor {
  pointer-events: none!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
Color: <input id="color" type="color" value="#ff0000"><br/>
Brush size: <input id="size" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="20"><br/>
Brush opacity: <input id="opacity" type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5"><br/>
<div id="cont">
  <canvas id="draw" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
  <canvas id="cursor" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. I actually came to pretty much the same conclusion above but I didn't have to create an extra 'layer' on top of the canvas.

Comment: @PaulRedmond: Yes, you do not absolutely need the second layer. I use it because I perform image processing on the drawing layer and having the cursor there (e.g. "seeing" its pixels) would not be helpful. With two layers everything is greatly separated :)

Comment: Good point. I was thinking about that for saving or serialising images as I have to hide the cursor every time. Same with when I reset the canvas, I have to then create the cursor again.

Comment: Yeah, there are several use cases where multiple layers (in my app there are currently four of them) will be helpful. But be sure that the use of CSS `pointer-events` on old IE will not get you into trouble ;) http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: I'm kind of coming back to this solution now to rethink, because the use of undo/redo is causing problems as the cursor itself is a canvas object and is being removed/added back with undo/redo.